# Android Asset FileNotFound Exception Using Kotlin and Android NDK C++

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, android-ndk, assets

I am trying to read `.obj` files in the `assets/` folder by passing the `AssetManager` object from my Kotlin script to the JNI interface, where I can use C++ to parse the `.obj` files and add it to my OpenGL scene. But the app is not finding any files in my assets folder.

I grab the AssetManager and attempt to pass it to my JNI inside of my renderer class, under the `OnSurfaceCreated` callback:

Kotlin File:

```kotlin
private external fun loadModels(assetManager: AssetManager): Void //Loaded correctly from companion object
private lateinit var manager: AssetManager
override fun onSurfaceCreated(unused: GL10, config: EGLConfig?) {
    manager = Resources.getSystem().assets //Gets the asset manager (poorly documented)
    loadModels(manager)
    manager.open("hello.txt") //Throws FileNotFoundException
}
```

C++ file:

```cpp
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <android/asset_manager.h>
#include <android/asset_manager_jni.h>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
Java_com_example_mypackage_glRenderer_loadModels(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject asset_manager) {
    AAssetManager* pAssetManager = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, asset_manager);
    if (pAssetManager == nullptr) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "GL_JNIConnector.cpp", "Failed to load asset manager");
        //Break
        exit(1);
    }
    //Loop through all files in Models folder
    AAssetDir* pModelsDirectory = AAssetManager_openDir(pAssetManager, "Models/");
    //AAssetDir_rewind(pModelsDirectory);
    const char* filename = AAssetDir_getNextFileName(pModelsDirectory); //Incorrectly returns NULL
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "GL_JNIConnector.cpp", "%s", filename);
}
```

But my `AAssetDir_getNextFileName(pModelsDirectory)` keeps returning `NULL`, when the files are present in my assets folder, AND unzipping the .apk file also shows they were added to the app correctly.

I tested it within the Kotlin by making up a `hello.txt` file and trying to access it in Kotlin using `manager.open("hello.txt")` and this also throws a `FileNotFoundException`

This is my directory:

[image: Image of assets directory]

Even hovering over the filename in my code points to the file in my assets folder, why can't the app find it in runtime?

Pulling apart the APK with Android Studio shows my assets folder intact in the `.apk` file

[image: Image of Android Studio APK Analyzer]

Comment: Where is `assets/` within the overall project? It should be a child of `main/` or another relevant source set. If it is in the right spot, if you use APK Analyzer in Android Studio, do you see the asset in the APK?

Comment: It is directly under `src/main` and the APK Analyzer shows the correct files in the assets folder

Comment: From the documentation for `Resources.getSystem`: _"Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only system resources (no application resources)"_.

Comment: Seems to me like you need a `Context` (e.g. an `Activity` or `Application`) on which you can call `getAssets` to get a suitable `AssetManager`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I grabbed my asset manager using

```kotlin
manager = Resources.getSystem().assets
```

which only gets me access to system resources, not application resources. Instead, I should have passed my context from my surface view class to the renderer class

```kotlin
//Surface View Class
class glSurfaceView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : GLSurfaceView(context, attrs)
//Renderer Class
class glRenderer(private val context: Context) : GLSurfaceView.Renderer
```

so that I could get my asset manager simply using

```kotlin
manager = context.assets
```

Thanks to @Michael for pointing that out